# VBA Self-Function returns #VALUE! Error on cell, while in Function window returns the actual value correctly

Tags: excel, vba, function

function i wrote below is taking one range which i have some conditional formatting on (for font color), and another one cell range for comparing color. Function is counting how many cells in the big range having the same font color as the one cell range.

```
Function CountColor(rng As Range, clr As Range) As Integer

  Dim c As Range
  Dim a As Integer
  a = 0

  For Each c In rng
      If c.DisplayFormat.Font.Color = clr.Font.Color Then
          a = a + 1
      End If
  Next

  CountColor = a

End Function
```

Now, problem is - in the function window, the actual result is coming correctly, while in the cell itself, i'm getting #VALUE! error.

Comment: So you assign the result of the function to a cell ? Check this out if it helps somehow https://support.office.com/en-us/article/How-to-correct-a-VALUE-error-15e1b616-fbf2-4147-9c0b-0a11a20e409e

Comment: See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838814(v=office.15).aspx: "Note that the DisplayFormat property does not work in user defined functions..."

Comment: `c.DisplayFormat.Font.Color = clr.Font.Color Then`

Should Become

`c.Font.Color = clr.Font.Color Then`

Comment: @AxelRichter That pretty much nails it. If this isn't a duplicate you could post this as an answer. I wonder what is behind that odd restriction.

Comment: I suspect that the problem is that conditional formatting might depend on cells other than the cell that contains that formatting. If UDFs could get at the displayed conditional formats and these conditional formats depend (perhaps indirectly) on the value of the UDF then a subtle circular reference could be set up. Just a guess though. The workaround is to replace a function that checks color by a function that checks the condition(s) which trigger that color.

Comment: Excel refreshes the formatting layer (which includes conditional formats) after the calculation cycle has completed, and only actually refreshes the visible portion of the formatting layer. So making a UDF that looks at conditional formatting would be so unreliable that MSoft decided not to allow it.

Comment: @CharlesWilliams, thanks for the explanation to the issue. I get it. So we will do one of two things - either replicate the logic of the conditional formatting to the function itself, or create a hidden column which will get numeric value per the same logic, and the function will be based on that.

Answer (score 0):

The following code worked for me but not with conditional formatting:

```
Option Explicit

Function CountColor(rng As Range, clr As Variant) As Variant
Dim c As Range
Dim a As Integer

a = 0
For Each c In rng
    If c.Font.color = clr.Font.color Then
        a = a + 1
    End If
Next c

CountColor = a
End Function
```

If I simply change the font color apart from conditional formatting it works. But for some reason it won't work, otherwise.

Comment: so what is the point ? this is what the PO wants, to see how many cells in a given range have met a certain criteria in the Conditional Formating range

Comment: @ShaiRado I'm simply stating I don't think it's possible but sharing what did work. It may have to do with a dependent cell as John Coleman alluded to.

Answer (score -1):

As multiple people have mentioned in the comments - The DisplayFormat property doesn't work in user defined functions. Therefore, if you remove `.DisplayFormat.` from your function it should work as expected.

```
Function CountColor(rng As Range, clr As Range) As Integer

  Dim c As Range
  Dim a As Integer
  a = 0

  For Each c In rng
      If c.Font.Color = clr.Font.Color Then
          a = a + 1
      End If
  Next
  CountColor = a
End Function
```

Comment: have you tested it with font that is modifed by a criteria met in the Conditional Formatting ? It doesn't recognize colors (fonts and backgrounds) modifed by the Conditional formating, see Chip Pearson link: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/cfcolors.htm