# Function to return interior colour of conditional formatted cell

Tags: excel, vba, colors, conditional-formatting

I want a function that returns a value for the colour index of a conditionally formatted cell.

It is being used to check a number of cells in a row that if they highlighted using conditional formatting then an action will be required - it is simpler to check if there is a colour in the cell rather than create a combined conditional formula covering the conditions of all the cells. Or so I thought..

The code below is returning a #VALUE error although the code works in a msg box..

```
Function fillcolour(rng as Range) as variant

    fillcolour=rng.Displayformat.Interior.ColorIndex

End Function
```

Expect to see a value for the colour index returned but getting #VALUE

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54608468/10908769) about `DisplayFormat` by conditional formatting (resulting from `FormatConditions`).

Comment: `Range.FormatConditions.Count` shows the number of format conditions of a cell. If 0, then that cell is not affected by any `FormatCondition`.

Comment: Thank you Asger - that was driving me nuts! The Count function has got me up and rolling again!

Comment: Spoke too soon.. I tested it on a range that CF cells and no CF cells which is fine. The problem is in the live sheet all Cells have CF so thsi won't differentiate. I need to pick out the cells where the CF is effectively banks because criteria haven't been met to apply a CF colour. Back to drawing board..

Comment: You can compare `rng.Interior.Color`with `rng.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color`, but not within a user defined function, as @AAA already wrote.

Comment: See the comments to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40239069/10908769) question, especially the last ones concerning Microsoft's reasons for that behaviour and a (maybe difficult) workaround.

Comment: Ive had a look at the link above esp the possible solution http://www.cpearson.com/excel/cfcolors.htm but that looks way too complicated for current situation. I've ended going back to manual and creating the conditions in some helper cells for each row showing which cells have met the conditional formatting criteria in that row which I can then  aggregate back into a single measure. It's a compromise but it avoids a mega formula which would be impossible to pass on to users and gets around the CF Function issue. Thanks for helping me through this.

Answer (score 1):

To use the change event:

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Call fillcolour(Cells(1, 1))
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub



Function fillcolour(ring As Range) As Variant

    fillcolour = ring.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color
    Cells(1, 2) = fillcolour

End Function
```

Each time you change the contents of a cell it will show you the background color in cell B1 (even if it comes from a conditional format).

However, this event returns a target with the row and column that caused the event (Target.Row, Target.Column, among many other things). You can use this target to detect the change you have made directly on the cell.

This event does not occur when the cells change during a new calculation. Use the Calculate event to detect a change in your range / cell.

Comment: That's really cool edu.  I didn't know you could get the CF color of a cell.  The CF sits on top of the cell, right.  I believe it is not actually in the cell itself, right. Anyway, nice work!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried?:

```vb
Function fillcolour(ring as Range) as variant

fillcolour=rng.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color

End Function
```

assign it to the event change of the cell

Comment: yes I did but this doesn't return the colour of a cell thats had colour applied via conditional formatting - its returning 16777215 which I guess is the no fill colour value

Comment: I don't need to know the CF colour value - I just need to know if CF has been applied. Is there a way to see that?

Comment: How do I assign the function to an event change of the cell?

Comment: All Excel sheets have the Worksheet_Change event. I show you an example.

Answer (score 0):

Please see this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.displayformat) on why you are having this issue. You can't use the `DisplayProperty` in user-defined functions. It works in the VBA environment or when called from a Message Box, but not when called from the Worksheet. The workaround is to remove `.DisplayFormat` from the code, as this:

```
Function fillcolour(rng as Range) as variant

fillcolour=rng.Interior.ColorIndex

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to Asger to helping out here. I now have a function as follows:

```
Function CFCheck(rng as range) as Integer

CFCheck = rng.FormatConditions.Count

End Function
```

So it can then trigger an action if the value returned is >0

On further testing realised this function just differentiates between cells that have CF and those that don't which is helpful but not in the situation I have. I need something that looks at a cell that has CF but the CF hasn't applied  colour because conditions haven't been met.

Answer (score 0):

Thought I'd add a recent project based on the above code that I used to find the colours of CF cells, might help someone, thanks for the above.

Cell M1 - Holds the colour code - ie, 255 red, 5287936 green

Cell N1 - top leftmost cell in the range

Cell O1 - bottom rightmost cell in the range

Output in M2 - count of CF colour in the range

Link a button for forced updates to

In Module:

```
    Global start_cell As String
    Global end_cell As String
    Global find_colour As Double
    Global found_colour As Double
    Global totalN As Integer
    Global Setup As Boolean
    Global x1 As String
    Global x2 As String
    Global y1 As String
    Global y2 As String

Function Setup_Now()

    start_cell = (Range("N1").Value)
    end_cell = (Range("O1").Value2)
    find_colour = (Range("M1").Value2)
    
    x1 = convertrow(start_cell)
    x2 = convertrow(end_cell)
    y1 = convertcol(start_cell)
    y2 = convertcol(end_cell)

End Function

Function convertrow(rng As String)

    convertrow = Range(rng).Row

End Function

Function convertcol(rng As String)

    convertcol = Range(rng).Column

End Function

Function fillcolour(rng As Range) As Variant

    fillcolour = rng.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color

End Function

Function reset()
    
    Application.EnableEvents = True
 
End Function

Sub Calculate()
    
    Call reset
    Range("M2").Value = "=2+2"
    
End Sub
```

In Worksheet Sheet:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()

    Call reset
    DoEvents
    
    totalN = 0
    x = 0
    y = 0
    
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    
    If Setup = False Then
        Call Setup_Now
        Setup = True
    Else
    'do nothing
    End If
    
        For x = x1 To x2
            For y = y1 To y2
                found_colour = fillcolour(Cells(x, y))
                If found_colour = find_colour Then: totalN = totalN + 1
            Next
        Next


    
    Debug.Print totalN, x, y
    Range("M2").Value = totalN
        
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    
  End Sub
```